# how to I added project Y to Project X and project X to project Z and fix the problem build path

Tags: java, eclipse, import, buildpath

[image]

how  to I added project Y to Project X and added project X to project Z and fix problem build path and the run project in eclipse?

Answer (score 0):

In the ***Git Repositories*** view **right-click** the ***jmab*** repository and choose ***Import Projects...***.